# HTML5 canvas Snake game

Tags: javascript, html5, coordinate-system, canvas, snake-game

My most recent project is this simple Snake game, and I would like to know what you think of it and if you have any suggestions.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var keys = new Array([]);
var body = [ //Body of snake
 {
  "x": 6,
  "y": 0
 },
 {
  "x": 5,
  "y": 0
 },
 {
  "x": 4,
  "y": 0
 },
 {
  "x": 3,
  "y": 0
 },
 {
  "x": 2,
  "y": 0
 },
 {
  "x": 1,
  "y": 0
 }
];

var food = [ //I put this in an array in case I decide to have multiple apples on screen or multiple types of apples
 {
  "x":15,
  "y":15
 }
];

var snake = new Object({});
snake.allowedWhen = 1; //When snake.allowedCount reaches this number, the snake will move once
snake.allowedCount = 0;
snake.direction = "right";
snake.points = 0;
snake.startLength = 6;

var boardX = 1;
var boardY = 0;
var board = [];

var opacity = 1;

var Interval;

var graphicalDecay = false;
var rotCount = 0;

for (var load = 0;load < (40*40);load++){ //Generates board in board array
 if (boardY < 41){
  board.push(boardX + "x" + boardY);
  if (boardX == 40){
   boardY ++;
   boardX = 0;
  }
  boardX ++;
 }
}

function main(){
 //VIEW HANDLING
 Interval = setInterval(function(){
  
  for (var i = 0;i < board.length;i++){ //Draws board

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(211,211,211,"+ opacity +")";
    if (board[i]){
     ctx.fillRect((board[i].split("x")[board[i].split("x").length - 2] * 15) - 1 ,(board[i].split("x")[board[i].split("x").length - 1] * 15) + 1,-14,14);
     
    }
     
  }
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  for (var x = 0; x < body.length; x++){ //Draws snake
   if (body[x]){
    ctx.fillRect((body[x].x * 15) - 1 ,(body[x].y * 15) + 1,-14,14);
   }
  }
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  if (food[0]){ //Draws food
    ctx.fillRect((food[0].x * 15) - 1 ,(food[0].y * 15) + 1,-14,14);
   }
   
  if (body[0].x == food[0].x && body[0].y == food[0].y){ //Adds two segments after feeding
   body.push({
    "x": body[body.length - 1].x,
    "y": body[body.length - 1].y
   });
   body.push({
    "x": body[body.length - 1].x,
    "y": body[body.length - 1].y
   });
   snake.points++;
   if (opacity > 0.2){
    opacity -= 0.05;
    if (graphicalDecay){
     ctx.rotate(0.001);
     rotCount++;
    } 
   }
   document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = "Score: " + snake.points + "<br />Snake length: " + body.length; //Updates "score board"
   setFood();
  }
  
  for (var h = 2;h < body.length;h++){ //Loss message and food resetter (Yes I am thinking about just making a loss function)
   if (body[0].x == body[h].x && body[0].y == body[h].y){
    clearInterval(Interval);
    alert("You lost with a score of " + snake.points + " and a length of " + body.length);
   }
   if (food[0].x == body[h].x && food[0].y == body[h].y){
    setFood();
   }
  }
  
  if ((body[0].x > 40 || body[0].x < 1) || (body[0].y > 39 || body[0].y < 0)){ //Other loss message
   clearInterval(Interval);
   alert("You lost with a score of " + snake.points + " and a length of " + body.length);
  }
  
  snake.allowedCount ++;
  if (snake.allowedCount > snake.allowedWhen){ //Allows controlled intervals of snake movement
   move(snake.direction);
   snake.allowedCount = 0;
  }
 }, 32);
 
 function setFood(){ //Does what the function name suggests
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40),y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40);
  if ((x > 40 || y > 40) || (x < 1 || y < 1)){
   x = 15, y = 15;
  }
  food[0].x = x;
  food[0].y = y;
 }
 
 function move(direction){ //Controls movement
  switch(direction){ //Pushes every object in the body array down and then removes the last object
   case "up":
    body.unshift(
    {
     "x": (body[0].x),
     "y": (body[0].y - 1)
    }
    );
    body.pop();
    break;
   case "down":
    body.unshift({
     "x": (body[0].x),
     "y": (body[0].y + 1)
    });
    body.pop();
    break;
   case "left":
    body.unshift({
     "x": (body[0].x - 1),
     "y": (body[0].y)
    });
    body.pop();
    break;
   case "right":
    body.unshift({
     "x": (body[0].x + 1),
     "y": (body[0].y)
    });
    body.pop();
    break;
  }
 }
 
 function doKeyDown(e){ //Keyboard input
   keys[e.keyCode] = true;
   input();
 }
     
 function doKeyUp(e){keys[e.keyCode] = false;}
 
 function setDir(direction){ //Prevents one from backslithering into one's self
  if (snake.direction == "right" && direction != "left")
   snake.direction = direction;
  if (snake.direction == "left" && direction != "right")
   snake.direction = direction;
  if (snake.direction == "up" && direction != "down")
   snake.direction = direction;
  if (snake.direction == "down" && direction != "up")
   snake.direction = direction;
 }
 
 function input(){ //Handles ur darn keystrokes, makes em' nice n' legible
  if (87 in keys && keys[87]) //up
   setDir("up");
  if (83 in keys && keys[83]) //down
   setDir("down");
  if (65 in keys && keys[65]) //left
   setDir("left");
  if (68 in keys && keys[68]) //right
   setDir("right");
 }
  
 window.addEventListener("keydown", doKeyDown, true);
 window.addEventListener("keyup", doKeyUp, true);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Snake</title>
 <style>
    body {
   background:gray;
    }
 #points {
  float:right;
  font-size:2em;
 }
 </style>
 
 
 <body>
   
   <canvas id="canvas" style="margin-left:15%;border:2px solid blue;" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
   <h2 id="points"><button onclick="main();this.style.opacity = 0;document.getElementById('points').innerHTML = 'Score: ' + snake.points + '<br />Snake length: ' + snake.startLength;">Start</button></h2>
   <button onclick="location.reload();">Restart</button><button onclick="graphicalDecay = !graphicalDecay;">Enable graphical decay</button>
   
   
 </body>
 
 <script src="js/snake.js"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: I didn't found how to play, even though the code suggest using arrow keys. Is it a limitation of stackexchange snippets? Also hitting the restart button gave me `Error {"message": "uncaught exception: out of memory", "filename": "", "lineno": 0, "colno": 0}`

Comment: You use W,A,S,D to move and the restart button works fine for me.